# React app throwing error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

The relevant line is here in bundle.js:

```
exports["default"] = _react.PropTypes.shape({
      subscribe: _react.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      dispatch: _react.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      getState: _react.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    });
```

I just upgraded to React 16, and have followed this [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.proptypes) to adjust PropTypes. I only have one component which references prop types, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
    class Authentication extends Component {
        static contextTypes = {
            router: PropTypes.object
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here are my dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "loaders": "^1.1.3",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
```

EDIT 2: Even when I comment out this line, the same error appears. But this line is the only place in the entire project where I mention prop types. What gives?

```
static contextTypes = {
            router: PropTypes.object
        }
```

Comment: Did you install [prop-types](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types) package?

Comment: @bennygenel I did.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party components from other packages?

Comment: @bennygenel such as what?

Comment: Please add complete component code.

Comment: For this particular component, or overall? 

I'm using react-spinkit.

Comment: You added prop-types as dev dependency. I thing it should be regular dependency. run `npm uninstall --save-dev prop-types && npm install --save prop-types`. This might solve the proplem.

Comment: @bennygenel Nope, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of `react-spinkit` is not ready for React 16.0 because it still uses the now unsupported `React.PropTypes`:

[Relevant code on GitHub](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/react-spinkit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=React.PropTypes&type=)

Last commit was on May, 22. I am afraid that you will not be able to upgrade React right now. But it looks like the current code is already a mix of the two, and there is only one line to change, so you could just submit to them a pull request with that change.